# Dynamically create new variables or work with an array

Tags: java, android, arrays, variables, kotlin

So I'm developer and currently working on an android to-do list app.

I'm looking for a way to store the date entered by the user:

- time
- title
- description
- etc..

Is there is a way to create variables dynamically ? *(e.g. task1, task2, etc..)*

Or should I work with 3 arrays for the time, title, description.

For example:

```
Time = ["5pm","4:15pm","6:30am"]
Title = ["Pick up the kids","meet Ammy"]
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should create a custom class like `Task`. As you don't know howmany tasks there will be, you will not use an array but a `List` such as `ArrayList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating a class Task and keep them in a list?

```
data class Task(val title: String, val time: String)

val tasks = listOf(Task(“Meet Amy”, “5pm”), Task(“Pick up kids”, “3pm”)
```

Comment: Am I obliged to use Val? because the user may want to make some changes. And thank you so much.

Comment: Ofcourse not. You can use `var` or `val` whatever suits your requirements. It would be a good idea indeed to have the Task class properties as `var` as the user may naturally make changes to the tasks

Comment: I am sorry for coming back, I've seen a lot of people using arraylists for the same purpose. For example storing people names and ages and then print them out aside. (In my case Title and time). Even the guys who commented on my question suggested to use an arraylist. My question is, can you please make it clearer for me on how to use this method? Thanks for helping.

Comment: @funris it is better that you ask a new question with the exact problem that you’re having.